# Is there any way to live edit your local html file but the output appears instantly on chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I like how when I use F12 on chrome I can edit a page live and check the source files and all that, but I would like to be able to use this on my own website so that every edit I make using F12 is instantly saved to the local html/css file. I like the live output is what I mean. Are there any programs like this? I've tried extensions as well but they all seem to be standalone nothing to do with the website I am browsing through. Is there any way to run F12 as the owner of the website?

Comment: No, its **NOT** possible.

Answer (score 1):

No its **NOT** possible.

However, you can use a scrapping software like **Httrack** and copy the entire remote website's CSS, JS and HTML files on your local system and then you can edit files manually using any text editor or IDE of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. This is my website that I've scripted. And isn't this just useing ctrl + s on a website? Anyway I found a program I can use. http://liveweave.com/

Comment: The program you named in comment requires source codes already available with you while your question was related to "How can you make changes directly from chrome (no matter local site or remote)
In that case (as per your question), HTTrack is gonna be useful in case you wont have source codes locally with you. 

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.